# Cannot get php generated page to download a a pdf

Tags: php

I have a php script that allows you to input your name and then create a certificate, this part works fine but wish the completed certificate to be downloaded as a pdf.

I have searched many forums and sites but cannot figure out how to do this and am very confused and baffled.

The php live test version can be seen at
http://gmdesign.org.uk/xxx/h

Its taken me 4 months to just create that as php is just not my thing and it was 4 month of stress, am asking out of desperation now if someone can add the correct code for me so the certificate downloads as a pdf  the code is here:

http://gmdesign.org.uk/xxx/h/script1.zip

when you enter name and proceed then generate certificate it works fine but when you click download the generated pdf is all wrong it does not show your name and also shows rest of page as if its a print out

thanks

Comment: Thats not a pdf, thats a table with css which you want to be a pdf, try a library like TCPDF to create an actual pdf file.

Comment: while this is not a great approach - Pdfcrowd does not have access to the session variables, but if you put them in the url it could be made to work

Comment: dagon, how do i go about this, am asking for help as totally confused.  i need to have an option for someone to enter a name and have it printed as a pdf , if mine wont work what other script can i use

Comment: where is your script??????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Dragon's solution, use $_GET variables, example...

At top of your page, place:

```
$fullName = $_GET['fullname'];
```

then you can use: hxxp://gmdesign.org.uk/xxx/h/certificate.php?fullname=Full Name

The $fullName var will then be whatever you put in it in the URL.

```
Example: <? echo($fullName); ?> would echo "Full Name"
```

Then I think he is saying to then save it on pdfcrowd like "http://gmdesign.org.uk/xxx/h/certificate.php?fullname=Full Name" which will save your certificate template as a PDF with the name "Full Name"

However, if you don't want to use a third party to convert the page to PDF, check out TCPDF like Koen recommended, or look at http://wkhtmltopdf.org

Comment: sven i tried adding that but no difference, it still does as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phpToPDF](http://www.phptopdf.com) library to create PDF from html file

You have already done coding to generate certificate html file now you have to give that file in phpToPDF libarary so it convert that html to pdf & store it on your server then you have to give that link to download button for download that certificate pdf file..

For phoToPDF library you need API key that you get once you registered with that library.

Comment: i tried that and added the code but it did not do anything, no errors, no generating pdf, nothing.     can you add it to the script and try it yourself.